# Storing a Class, Method or Object inside variable in ObjC

Tags: objective-c, generics, objective-c-runtime

I'm trying to store in a variable something that can be either a Class a Method (struct objc_class & struct objc_method) or any Object. Initially I thought about just storing it in a plain id variable but I get bridging problems that I can't seem to get rid of. Is there a suitable way to do this?

```
-(void)setV:(id)v{
 id val=v;
}

[obj setV:class_getInstanceMethod(c, NSSelectorFromString(@"foo")];
```

Error:

```
Implicit conversion of C pointer type 'Method' (aka 'struct objc_method *') to Objective-C pointer type 'id' requires a bridged cast
```

Comment: Do you think it would be a good idea to show code, along with compiler complaints, for these _bridging problems_ you speak of?

Comment: What does "as Method (structs)" mean?

Comment: Apparently, this user prefers to keep an air of mystery about the question.

Comment: @zaph Questions and Mysteries are strongly linked :)

Comment: Question with mysteries and lack of answers are strongly linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `union`:

```
union ClassOrMethodOrUnsafeUnretainedObject
{
    Class c;
    Method m;
    __unsafe_unretained id o;
};

union ClassOrMethodOrUnsafeUnretainedObject temp;
temp.o = @"Test";
```

If you also want to store which kind of object you have stored, you can combine the `union` with an `enum` inside a `struct`:

```
struct CombinedType {
    union {
       Class c;
       Method m;
       __unsafe_unretained id o;
    } value;
    enum {
        kCombinedTypeClass,
        kCombinedTypeMethod,
        kCombinedTypeUnsafeUnretainedObject,
    } type;
};

struct CombinedType temp;
temp.value.o = @"Test";
temp.type = kCombinedTypeUnsafeUnretainedObject;
```

Comment: @trojanfoe I have added your suggestion to my answer. In most cases it is good to also remember which kind of value you have stored.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you very much :)